# Regex to parse Email Form "To" field

Tags: php, regex, email-validation

If there is one that could handle this, what would be the correct regex pattern to extract email addresses from a string coming from an email form "To" line, that allows the addresses to be delimited by commas ",", semicolons ";", spaces, or any combination of the three. The regex also has to be able to ignore "noise" text, such as if an address is enclosed in "<" and ">" characters, or has an actual name next to the email address. For example, from this string that was in the To field:

```
"Joe Smith" <jsmith@example.com>, kjones@aol.com; someoneelse@nowhere.com mjane@gmail.com
```

The pattern should be able to return the following matches of:
jsmith@example, kjones@aol.com, someoneelse@nowhere.com, mjane@gmail.com

I am using PHP, so if this can't be done in single regex then im definitely open to other PHP-based solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Use an email-parsing library. There is no need to do this yourself. (You're not the first PHP programmer to need to parse email headers.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

(courtesy of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)) as in

```
preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Note the `/i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869873/how-retrieve-email-all-ids-from-a-file) for an explanation of the drawbacks of regexes for finding e-mail addresses in a string.

Comment: thank you for allowing `+` in my email address... lately i've ran into a few signup forms that don't allow it...really annoys me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the regex from http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php, and only modified it slightly.

```
$string = '"Joe Smith" <jsmith@example.com>, kjones@aol.com; someoneelse@nowhere.com mjane@gmail.com';
$email_regex = "/[^0-9< ][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*@[A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}/";
preg_match_all($email_regex, $string, $matches);
$emails = $matches[0];
```

Now $emails will have an array with all your email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

While your question was specific to RegEx and Tim gave you a great answer, for people looking for a simple solution, look at mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses on page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php

Note this is not a standard PHP function and requires installing the extension.  Economy hosting solutions may not allow you to install the PECL extension.